# Plotting line graph in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, graph, plot

I would like to plot [these data](http://cdiac.ornl.gov/ftp/trends/co2/barrsio.co2) as a simple scatterplot/line graph, which would show the linear change of CO2 levels. However, I cannot plot it as I am unable to vectorise the matrix into proper vector. Could anyone help me finding the right method?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you managed to read in the data?

Comment: Do you want to plot CO2 levels for all months altogether as a function of year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution needs the [`development version of data.table v1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

`fread` from the `data.table` package does a good job in reading in the data, while omitting the unneeded lines of text.  You can then reshape the data using `melt`, also from `data.table`, ready to plot.

```
# libraries
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

# read in data
dat <- fread("http://cdiac.ornl.gov/ftp/trends/co2/barrsio.co2", data.table=F)

# remove spaces in names
setnames(dat, names(dat), make.names(names(dat)))

# reshape data
dat_m <- melt(dat[-ncol(dat)], id.vars="V1")

# plot
ggplot(dat_m, aes(variable, value, group=1)) +
       geom_point() +
       geom_line() +
       facet_wrap(~ V1, nrow=6)
```

To produce

[image]

Or if you want to plot the average value per year

```
ggplot(dat, aes(V1, Ann..Ave.)) +
       geom_point() +
       geom_line() +
       scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1974, 2007, 5))
```

To give

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Using Base R Functions**

Just as an alternate perspective using only base R functions

```
 ### Download the file
    download.file("http://cdiac.ornl.gov/ftp/trends/co2/barrsio.co2", 
                  "~/Downloads/so-data.txt")
    ### Read the data line by line
    raw.dat <- readLines(file("~/Downloads/so-data.txt"))
    ### Extract the column names
    col.names.index <- grep("jan.*feb", raw.dat, ignore.case=TRUE)
    col.names <- raw.dat[col.names.index]
    col.names <- strsplit(col.names, split='\t')[[1]]
    (col.names <- col.names[-1])
    ### Extract the row names
    row.names.index <- grep('^[12][019][0-9][0-9]', raw.dat)
    row.names <- raw.dat[row.names.index]
    row.names <- substr(row.names, 1, 4)
    ### Extract the data
    data.rows.index <- row.names.index
    data.rows <- raw.dat[row.names.index]
    ### I had to fix the first row of the data as it was missing a tab
    ### I don't know if this is true in the original file
    data.rows[1] <- paste(data.rows[1],'\t')
    ### convert to a matrix
    data.rows <-
      matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(data.rows,
                                        split='\t'))),
             byrow=TRUE,
             ncol=14)

    ### drop the first and last columns: rownames, ave.
    data.rows <- data.rows[,-c(1,13)]
    colnames(data.rows) <- col.names[-13]
    rownames(data.rows) <- row.names

    ### Make the plots
    par(mfrow=c(9,4))
    par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))  ### prevents margins too large error
    for (i in rownames(data.rows))
      plot(data.rows[i,], type='l',main=i)
```

The plots are as follows:
[image: These plots need to be prettied up.]

Comment: where do you get the data from `~/Downloads/so-data.txt`? remotely or from your local machine?

Comment: I saved the web page linked by OP to my downloads as text

Comment: @teelou I have modified the code to download the file directly

Comment: Im not great with regex, but you can shorten your code. .. but more importantly you dont need to amend the file with an extra tab, by using `skip <-  grep("*****", raw.dat, fixed=T);  end <-  grep("2007", raw.dat, fixed=T); read.table(text=raw.dat, sep="\t", fill=T, header=T, skip=max(skip), nrow=(end-max(skip)-1))`

Comment: @user20650 the "*****" is not valid regex but I agree the code can always be made more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use principal components to find which month has more variation in CO2.

That might be a good way to look at your data based on a particular locality.

**After you load your data into R:**

```
PCA = princomp(~Jan+Feb+March+April+May+June+July+Aug+Sept+Oct+Nov+Dec,Data,cor=TRUE)

PCA

loadings(PCA)
plot(PCA)
biplot(PCA)
```

The biplot we will data down your data into the component with the most variation.